# scilab - find the integral of an exponential with matrix

Tags: matrix, exponential, integral, scilab

How do I do this:

H = integral( exp(At) * B dt), from 0.0 to 0.1?

The objective is to develop a discrete state observer from a continuous one.
However, a never get a answer from scilab.

Comment: integrate
But it does not accept matrix

Comment: Have you read the docs? why don't you use http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/inttrap.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably this:
C. Van Loan: Computing integrals involving the matrix exponential, IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control, vol.23, no.3, pp. 395–404, Jun 1978

For example, from here:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/computing.integrals.involving.Matrix.Exp.pdf